# Update confirmation email on the event checkout_onepage_controller_success_action

Tags: magento

I’m facing an issue and i’m wondering if you could help me with it ..

I need to update my confirmation email on the following event:  checkout_onepage_controller_success_action, and send it only after my updates are done inside it..

Problem is I don’t find where is sent the confirmation email in the code ? and it’s probably not an observer on an event no ?

Maybe you could help me with it because i need to update this email with some important Information that I only got after I have a payment confirmation ..

Anyway I wish you a nice sunday and maybe you will be able to help me,

All the best for your different projects,

Anselme

PS i'm using magento 1.4.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of the class `Mage_Sales_Model_Order`, there is a function `sendNewOrderEmail` which fires the email for the order. This is called by the checkout model (`Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage`, line 741 on my install). Depending on what type of information you are looking for, you may not be able to guarantee that this information is available at the time that the framework wants to send the email.

If that is the case, you could override the sales_order class and change the contents of that function. Rather than sending the email immediately, you could override the function to check for the presence of the necessary data, and send it only if the data is available. If the data is not available, you would want to add it to some sort of job queue so that it could be periodically checked for the right information and sent when necessary.

The reason for overriding the sales_order class itself is that there are several other places in the framework where the `sendNewOrderEmail` function is called, and changing it g

Comment: thanks joseph for your answer  [quote] If the data is not available, you would want to add it to some sort of job queue so that it could be periodically checked for the right information and sent when necessary.[/quote] when you say this do you know how can I send a periodical check on a fonction with magento ? In fact i just need to update my downloadable links that i only retrieve on the event i Mentionned..  Anayway thanks and have a nice day

Comment: Periodic checks are naturally fulfilled using cron jobs. Look at app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml for an example of scheduling a job. You will need to keep track of which need to be sent yourself. I don't understand your second to last question.

Comment: thanks again joseph sorry for my confusing answer.. I was just saying that initially i posted this message because I'm using magento for downloadable content.. and i only get the downloadable links after the event i mentionned.. My server is indeed initiating a connection with a webservice (soap) and getting the links with the answer of the webservice and that's where i need to update on one hand my mail confirmation but on the other hand my database table.. i'm now wondering if it would not be better to create a new function inside  Mage_Sales_Model_Order rather than using an observer on even