# magento order confirmation email being sent to boss instead of customer service

Tags: magento, confirmation-email

One of my clients is very annoyed that he is getting all the reply emails from customers that replied to an order invoice sent to their email. I have done a mass search of his email in all of the tables in the database and also do not see it in any of the transactional email templates. Any idea of where else I can find this variable!?

I see $mailer->setSender(Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_IDENTITY, $storeId)); in the function that post refers to. Where do I find this xml_path_email_identity file?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312230/update-confirmation-email-on-the-event-checkout-onepage-controller-success-actio

Comment: I see $mailer->setSender(Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_IDENTITY, $storeId)); in the function that post refers to. Where do I find this xml_path_email_identity file?

Comment: its in Class Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice

Comment: it's also in Class Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment so you have to modify both

Comment: if you have problems overwriting it i suggest you look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871155/cant-override-mage-sales-model-order

Answer (score 0):

I guess he on some sort sort of mailing list, whch receives this email.

If you let him forward such an email to you, you might see the original sent to address in the mail header.

Furthermore the target email address can either be in core_config_data or in the code (depending on implementation).
If it is in core_config_data, it should be changeable by the magento backend interface.

Comment: Yeah, the Customer Receipt/Purchase Confirmation is being marked as sent by the owner of the company. Any way I can at least make the email no-reply?